# CSS Embossed (Inset) Text

Tags: css, firefox, emboss

I'm trying to give my headings a nice embossed look. It works great in Chrome, but Firefox bows out. How can I make this effect work in both? Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7p15s3nv/

And my CSS:

```
h1 {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -moz-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like `text` is a non-standard value implemented by webkit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility

Comment: check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/NeqCC/, I tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE11 all same result

Comment: this is a modified fiddle of the above one to mimic your text http://jsfiddle.net/h60n539t/

Comment: Looks like every does point at the same technque ;), it should not be so bad , is it ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I cant understand the reason for Downvote on my answer!

Comment: @Trix  I do not either !! 3 similar answers and 1 downvoted without explanatons, it's a non sense to me too

Answer (score 2):

maybe without background-clip, but a more 'classical' approach ?

```css
h1:first-of-type {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -moz-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
}
h1+h1 {
   color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 -2px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello there! webkit</h1>
<h1>Hello there! FF ?</h1>
```

fiddle to play with https://jsfiddle.net/7p15s3nv/5/

to test side by side in chrome and any other browser such as IE or FF

Comment: Close, but if you zoom in a lot you'll see that your suggestion doesn't have any shading. I was looking more for a way to make my code work in Firefox.

Comment: @GTSJoe well what you are using is not avalaible in FF nor IE (yet ?) , you have to go for an alternative that breaks fine where webkit experimental effects are not avalaible.        ......................    For the shade, i do not know if you can get exactly the same, you need to tune the shadows, add some blur to it or use one or a few more to redraw your desired effect. My answers points about a more effective  cross browsers technique,  not a ready made job but close enough to be minded. I wish you that there is a better option, i would enjoy to learn something.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the desired output?

[image]

```css
h1{
    font-size: 100px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #eee, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 2px 3px #eee;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is text</h1>
```

## UPDATE

This update is to cover the last comment from question author:

```css
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 200px;
    color: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 0 #EEE, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 2px 0 #EEE;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is text</h1>
```

Comment: No, there should be no background-color. The desired output is how it looks in Chrome, not Firefox.

Comment: This is just a drop shadow. The effect I'm going for is inset text, like embossed text.

Comment: @GTSJoe Is this not the desired output?

Comment: Trix, I did try your suggestion and it does look good with your color scheme, but I noticed that if you change the colors, then it looks way off. For example, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7p15s3nv/7/ changing colors does not produce the desired output. I need a method that works with ALL colors.

Comment: @GTSJoe If you want it in another color, you can change the color, not the shadow. try my UPDATE for a red one

Answer (score 0):

While background-clip is a valid CSS3 property, the text value in non-standard. That's why it does not work in most browsers.

A trick that might work for you is a combination of semi-transparent text (with rgba) and text-shadow like this:

```css
h1 { 
 color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
 /* #FFF should be the same as background color of the text */
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #fff, 0 0 0 #666, 3px 3px 6px #fff; 
  
  }
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only solution is to duplicate the text in a pseudo.

Not very easy to maintain, but it can work

In case you go with this solution, to make it easier to maintain would be to set the text in an attr in the element, and use this attr for the content of the pseudo

```css
.demo {
  font-size: 200px;
  color: darkgreen;
  position: relative;
}

.demo:after {
  content: "Hello";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 20px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.91);
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">Hello</div>
```